# How can I set position of root frame or window in Common Lisp ltk?

Tags: position, lisp, common-lisp, screen, ltk

I am outputting a window with 2 columns and 11 rows with LTK in Common Lisp. Unfortunately I cannot set the position on screen where it is displayed. Mostly it appears top left, sometimes to the right of my terminal window. How can I set its position to a predefined place on screen?

```
(let* ((mf (make-instance 'frame)))
      (grid mf 0 0)
      (setf subf (make-instance 'frame :master mf))
      (grid subf 1 0 :padx 10 :pady 5)
      (setf label (make-instance 'label :master subf :text "some text"))
      (grid label 1 0))
```

Comment: There appears to be a set-geometry function available. (set-geometry toplevel width height x y). Does this help? http://www.peter-herth.de/ltk/ltkdoc-single/ltkdoc.html

Comment: Thank you very much @Francis King. This was the solution.